# How to resolve "Can't downgrade database from version 2 to 1" in ActiveAndroid?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, activeandroid

I used ActiveAndroid ORM in my application and in AndroidManifest.xml we just need do define meta-data tag for database version like

```
<meta-data android:name="AA_DB_VERSION" android:value="2" />
```

but when i uninstall build and change Db version to 1 instead of 2 then After reinstalling it throws an error like **Can't downgrade database from version 2 to 1**

I don't know why it would happen because i completely uninstall application from my phone then also AA won't allow me to downgrade database version.

May be it's internally handle by AA but still is there any solution ?Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Errors like this one, please always specify your phones android version. This error may have multiple reasons, e.g.

Assuming you use API 23, google backs up all your application data. It will get redownloaded after reinstall.
Try clearing your application data and / or set [`android:allowBackup`](http://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html) to false in the manifest.

There may always be the possibility that the library you are using writes to external storage, in which case you will have to find and delete this file.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
Settings -> Apps -> All -> Dialer -> Force Stop -> Clear Data/Cache

Settings -> Apps -> All -> Phone -> Force Stop -> Clear Data/Cache
```

credit goes to AsadP from [oneplus forum](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/com-android-phone-has-stopped.143556/)